# KnockoutJs Components - add default class

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Knockout gives you two ways of instantiating a component, either with a custom html element or with the component binding.

However I have discovered a slight issue when trying to style the root component element. It's fine if you just use the custom element syntax as you can just assign css styles to that - however, if you then use the component binding, the css rules don't match and so they fail.

Ideally I want to support both scenarios as they both have their uses. If I could get knockout to add a class to the root component element which is just the component name it would solve the issue but reading the documentation it isn't clear where it would be best to do this.

I've already got a custom template loader which retrieves the template from an ajax call, but this template is just the inner html of the root node.

Basically I want this:

```
<my-custom-element>
...
...
<my-custom-element>
```

To become this:

```
<my-custom-element class="my-custom-element">
...
...
<my-custom-element>
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "createViewModel" method and access element in the component (e.g. to add some class):

```
ko.components.register('some-component', {
    viewModel: {
        createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
            var $element = $(componentInfo.element.children[0]);
            // some other code ...
        }
    },
    template: "<div></div>"
});
```